# Centos 7 and Docker 1.13.1 - Error Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers - No proxy and No DNS issue

Tags: docker, centos7, tripleo

I am facing this issue and I can find many people also facing this same issue mainly because of DNS and or Proxy.
But in my case, I don't have proxy, and I confirm the DNS is working well.

```
systemctl disable firewalld ; systemctl stop firewalld ; systemctl disable iptables  ; systemctl stop iptables ; iptables -F ; iptables -nL

[root@ ~]# systemctl status firewalld
   firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
[root@ ~]# systemctl status iptables
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
[root@ ~]# 

[root@ ~]# docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/hello-world ... 
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

[root@ ~]# # nslookup registry-1.docker.io
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 107.23.149.57
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.5.11.128
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.54.232.21
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 54.85.107.53
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.1.121.53
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 18.232.227.119
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 18.213.137.78
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.4.20.24
```

This issue can be always reproduced anytime:

1. Install a fresh Centos 7.7 or 7.8 (do yum update or even without)
2. on if-cfg, add DNS1 & DNS2 = <any public dns such as 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8>
3. Install Docker 1.13.1 (yum install docker (docker.x86_64 2:1.13.1-162.git64e9980.el7.centos))
4. Start Docker (systemctl start docker)
5. Disable firewalld and iptables
6. Pull any docker image (docker pull hello-world)
7. Error as above

Tried with Docker-CE and no issue at all:

1. Remove above docker (yum -y remove docker docker-client docker-client-latest docker-common docker-latest docker-latest-logrotate docker-logrotate docker-engine)
2. Install Docker-CE (yum install -y yum-utils; yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo; yum -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io)
3. Start Docker (systemctl start docker)
4. Pull any docker image (docker pull hello-world)
5. Image pulled successfully
6. <test uninstall docker-ce again, then install docker (1.13.1) again, then having the same error again>

I need this Docker 1.13.1 because it's the dependency of python-tripleoclient which I am trying to test this.

Does anyone also encounter this issue? Or perhaps did I miss something?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: Forgot to add, firewalld and iptables also already disabled, will edit above post. Also as you see that when I switch to docker-ce on the same setup, it is working fine.

Comment: python-tripleoclient should work with Docker CE. Contact its packager for assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked the question on [openstack-discuss mailing list](http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-discuss/2020-September/017098.html), but no answer about it.